# We are using Java7, I am trying to generate the ApiClient using yaml but having compilation issues

Tags: java, maven, yaml, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

This is the first time ever I am posting here and relatively new to Coding. Plugin used is as below: My senior pointed out the configuration you are using might not work for Java7. I am not sure whats the right set of configurations I need to use? I just copied this from other project not knowing much.

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/.../rest/ApiClient.java:[28,26] package javax.ws.rs.client does not exist

[ERROR] /C:/Users/.../rest/ApiClient.java:[29,26] package javax.ws.rs.client does not exist

[ERROR] /C:/Users/.../rest/api/ChangeRequestsApi.java:[10,42] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class AnyOfrequestSummarymoprequestNeListrequestContactsrequestConflicts
  location: package com.project.rest.model

pom.xml:
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
        <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>regular</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/xyz.yaml</inputSpec>
              <generatorName>java</generatorName>
              <output>${project.basedir}</output>
              <generateApiTests>true</generateApiTests>
              <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
              <withXml>true</withXml>
              <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
              <skipValidateSpec>true</skipValidateSpec>
              <environmentVariables>
                <supportingFiles>ApiClient.java,ApiResponse.java,ApiException.java,Configuration.java,JavaTimeFormatter.java,RFC3339DateFormat.java,JSON.java,Pair.java,ServerConfiguration.java,ServerVariable.java,StringUtil.java,Authentication.java,HttpBasicAuth.java,ApiKeyAuth.java,HttpBearerAuth.java</supportingFiles>
              </environmentVariables>
              <configOptions>
                <apiPackage>com.company.project.jbpm.rest.api</apiPackage>
                <modelPackage>com.company.project.jbpm.rest.model</modelPackage>
                <dateLibrary>java7</dateLibrary>
                <library>resteasy</library>
                <useTags>true</useTags>
              </configOptions>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: Are you sure you cannot switch to at least Java 8?

Comment: Haha I know. I wish I could. Anyways resolved the problem with many other 3rd party libraries. Will try to post about it soon. 